# Heroku: Proper way to assign a domain in your app

Tags: heroku, dns

its first time i am working with heroku on a project and i have to assign a domain to the app, so the application can run properly from the domain i have instead of heroku subdomain. Is there any Nameserver( dns addresses) i can give to my domain and get assigner or  its only works with domain mapping? thank you.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: In addition, you may wish to add a re-direct for your app to point requests to yourapp.herokuapp.com to your canonical domain. The implementation details will depend on your app type; if it's a Rack/Rails app you can use rack-contrib to assist.

Comment: @RyanDaigle thx for the mention. I had frwd wildcard & www but could make naked domain to play on heroku. I used an htaccess to redirect naked to www. and everything works fine now.

Comment: @HaCos instead of redirecting w/ an htaccess from your naked domain to your CNAME, I'd recommend using a DNS-level redirect instead: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords#subdomain_redirection

Comment: @RyanDaigle You were right, as heroku suggest, we should avoid naked domains and DNS A-records. In order to go hover this i used dnsimple.com , its an awesome service to manage all records & domains (has a pre-set tmpl for heroku as well thats makes it even easier)